# How to set an SVG label of an element in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

There is an SVG picture which embeds `text` and `tspan` elements:

```
<svg>
   <text y="5" x="9">
        <tspan style="text-anchor:end;" y="5" x="9" id="blueLabel">
        {{ displayLabelHere }}
        </tspan>
   </text>
</svg>
```

I'd like to use `computed` to fetch a label from an array (JSON), but when I try to get the ID the same way I got it in `methods`, I get `undefined` value:

```
computed: {
    displayLabelHere: function(e) {
      console.log(e.target.id); // console says undefined
    }
}
```

How to get the ID of that SVG element?

Comment: Is your Vue rendering the SVG?

Comment: @BertEvans: yes, the SVG is inside a template in the same component.